# In C: Unhandled exception : 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location. program won't run

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio tells me the problem with my code is in the line where

```
*p = *p1;
```

But I don't see what's wrong there.
The objective in this code is to build a function that will get a string and an int and will sort the string and return the letter in the index of the int.
For example for the string "build" it will sort it to "bdilu" if the int was 2 would return "i".
Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char letterAtIndex(char *s, int n);

void main(){
    char s, *arr = { "a string" };
    s=letterAtIndex(arr, 7);
    printf("%c", s);
    getch();
}
char letterAtIndex(char *s, int n){
    int t;
    char *p1 = s, *p2 = s, *p;
    while (*(++p2));
    while (p1 < p2){
        p = p1;
        while (p < p2){
            if (*p1>*p){
                t = *p;
                *p = *p1;
                *p1 = t;
            }
            p++;
        }
        p1++;
    }
    return s[n];
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00F81436 in justforstudy.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation writing location 0x00F85859.
```

Comment: Whats that looking like? You are writing somewhere your program isn't permitted to.

Comment: String literal can not be changed. A result of changing is undefined behavior. So change `*arr = { "a string" }` to  `arr[] = { "a string" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a string literal to your function `letterAtIndex`. you can't write to it. Change `char *arr = { "a string" };` to `char arr[] = { "a string" };` and it will work.`char arr[]` is an array of elemts with type `char` which is read and writeable:

```
int main(){
    char arr[] = { "a string" };
    char s = letterAtIndex( arr, 7 );
    printf( "%c", s );
    return 0;
}
```

An other possibility would be to allocate dynamic memory and copy the string into it.

```
#include <string.h> // strcpy
#include <malloc.h> // malloc, free

int main(){
    const char *str = "a string";
    char *arr = malloc( strlen(str ) + 1 );
    strcpy( arr, str );
    char s = letterAtIndex( arr, 7 );
    printf( "%c", s );
    free( arr );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A string literal is `const` in C++, which is why this code would give a deprecation warning over there. In C, it's not const-qualified.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behaviour to attempt changing a string literal. Use the type `const char *` for variables pointing to string literals to have the compiler help you spot when you attempt to do so.

You can fix your code by:

- making a copy of the passed in string and sort that one and return it (You will need to free it afterwards).
- Pass in a mutable buffer, e.g. by declaring `arr` as `char arr[]`